# Swiftで表示させた画像をピンチインアウトしたい

Tags: swift, 画像, pinchin

画像を表示して、ピンチを認識するようにまではできたのですが、いろいろなサイトを見て試してもうまくいきませんでした。(自分なりに書き換えてみたりした)
どうすればピンチイベントとして拡大縮小を設定できるのでしょうか？

Comment: せっかく _自分なりに書き換えてみたりした_ のであれば、差し支えない範囲で試行錯誤中のコードを質問に追記した方が適切な回答が得やすいのではないかと思います（覚えていれば、参考にしたサイトの情報とかも書いておくと良いかもしれません）。

Answer (score 1):

ピンチイベントから取得できるのは、指をどれだけ動かしたかという情報だけなので、
それを使って自分で拡大するコードを書く必要があります。
もしくは、UIScrollViewを使うと、自分で書かなくても良い感じに拡大してくれますよ。